# Is non-smoked nicotine a smoking cessation-aid?

Tags: smoking, recreational-drugs, nicotine, preventative-medicine, tobacco

I understand it is a consensus that in general, daily and along the day active smoking of anything (as well as passive smoking) is health damaging.

Teeth damage, lung damage, and complications are, as far as I know, the most likely problems from active, addiction based, cigarette smoking (of say, a pack a day).

I recall searching evidence for the usage of either nicotine tablets or tobacco capsules as smoking cessation aids but finding pretty much nothing.
Doing so might substitute mouthholding Swedish tobacco sackets (Snus) which as I understood can help avoiding (but not necessarily ceasing), smoking.
<sub>**Edit after answer:** I know people also use gums but I never came across usage of tablets or capsules instead gums.</sub>

Is non-smoked nicotine (especially in the form of nicotine tablets or capsules) a smoking cessation-aid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [nicotine replacement therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotine_replacement_therapy) is used in multiple forms, including a skin patch and oral dosing with gums and lozenges.

The purpose is to help avoid the side effects of nicotine withdrawal, while delivering nicotine at lower doses than is obtained through smoking, to help manage craving and eventually stop smoking entirely.

---

As far as the delivery mechanism, nicotine undergoes substantial first-pass metabolism in the liver. This could make it harder to dose, because you would need to give 3-4 times the sublingual dose to get the same plasma concentration, and because individual differences or drug interactions might make the extent of first-pass metabolism variable and unpredictable between individuals.

*Benowitz, N. L., Jacob III, P., & Savanapridi, C. (1987). Determinants of nicotine intake while chewing nicotine polacrilex gum. Clinical Pharmacology & Therapeutics, 41(4), 467-473.*

*Benowitz, N. L. (1996). Pharmacology of nicotine: addiction and therapeutics. Annual review of pharmacology and toxicology, 36(1), 597-613.*

Comment: Oh, sorry for not mentioning it in the question (I just did so in edit) --- I know the gum solution; I just never understood why I saw people using only gums and not tablets or capsules; please forgive me for this embarrassing mistake.

Comment: @JohnDoea Your question asks whether non-smoked nicotine is used.

Comment: Bryan yes - I wanted to emphasize the issue of tablets and capsules but I misphrased the question and for that I am sorry.

Comment: I did my best to fix the mistake and I also upvoted your answer.

Comment: @JohnDoea I don't believe nicotine tablets or capsules exist. Pure nicotine is a potent toxin and has long been used as a pesticide. So the reason is probably that they would be extremely dangerous. It's hard to accidentally (or intentionally) ingest too much nicotine with gums, patches and lozenges, but it would be very easy with pills.

Comment: @CareyGregory because as you know perhaps better than I, comments can get deleted on time, I think it is important that you will wrap these data in an answer such as "adding on top of what Bryan said...".

Comment: @JohnDoea I'm just speculating on the reason why there's no nicotine pill. I don't have any references to support an answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory I think the actual reasons may be related to poor gastric (or gastrointestinal) tolerance of nicotine associated with nausea/vomiting; I'll add a reference and expand my answer if I find one, or find another explanation.